# How do I wire a motor driver power supply?

Tags: arduino, dc-motor

I'm trying to wire and control [TB6612FNG Dual Motor Driver Carrier](http://www.pololu.com/catalog/product/713), but am doing something wrong. Why is the motor not running?

I have the vcc and gnd connected to a 5v power source, and ao1 and ao2 connected to my motor.

When connecting the power source directly to the motor, the motor runs.

pwma, ain1, ain2, and stby pins are connected the pins as expected from the sketch. I also have the gnd pin on the logic side of the board connected to a gnd pin on the arduino(uno v2). PWMA is connected to pin 5, which is a digital pin.

```
const int stby=2;
const int in1=3;
const int in2=4;
const int pwm=5;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(stby, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(pwm, OUTPUT);
  forward(255);
}

void loop() {
}

void forward(int speed)
{
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(stby, HIGH);
  analogWrite(pwm, speed);
}
```

Comment: This might help: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/12731/where-to-place-decoupling-capacitor

Comment: @antony.trupe, can you post a schematic of how **you** are physically wiring things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vcc is the logic supply, i.e it powers the chip. VMOT is the motor voltage. the chip has two H-bridge drivers that basically attach VMOT across the motor in either reverse or forward polarity. Both of these need to be powered. They give you two so you can use a higher voltage on VMOT which may be required by the motors.

Make sure you don't exceed the voltage specs:

Recommended motor voltage (VMOT): 4.5 – 13.5 V
Logic voltage (VCC): 2.7 – 5.5 V

If you put 5V on both Vcc and Vmot, they should be powered adequately.

There may be additional issues with your other wiring and code, but, I won't address them until you fix your power problem is resolved and we can be sure there are other issues.

**ADDED:**

Here is the schematic of the breakout board, this seems to show that you still need to attempt powering both.

[image: sch]

Vcc and Vmot are NOT connected on this board, have you tried using a multimeter to measure if they are on yours?

Comment: @antony.trupe: I am quite sure that both VMOT and Vcc need to be powered. VMOT does not power the chip. I explained this a little further above. This is required by the architecture of the driver chip (http://www.pololu.com/file/download/TB6612FNG.pdf?file_id=0J86) . It is a pretty typical architecture used by most of these driver chips.

Comment: @antony.trupe: The circuitry on your breakout board is a couple of decoupling caps and and a mostfet for polarity protection. i.e. the breakout board works almost identically to the chip it breaks out. You need to try what I am saying to verify, I have a valid point here based on the other datasheet.

Comment: @Anthony.trupe, If that is true, then the documentation is wrong. I worked off of the documentation and I am helping you interpret it, it is not kind to vote me down for attempting to help you based on the information given. You are effectively punishing me for taking the time to help.

Comment: Well... all the documentation contradicts what you are saying. Explain these specs: Recommended motor voltage (VMOT): 4.5 – 13.5 V, Logic voltage (VCC): 2.7 – 5.5 V. Why would there be different voltage ranges if you didn't need to power VCC and VMOT separately? Anyway, if you've answered your own question then post the answer.

Comment: @antony.trupe, a downvote tells the world that the poster is technically inaccurate in the eyes of at least one user. Why would you then ask that user to continue helping you with a technical problem if you have already stated they are wrong?

Comment: @antony.trupe, you have not posted an answer that seems valid yet. I think that dave has valid points, but as a moderator, I am only here to settle a seeming dispute. The reason your "answers" have been removed because they read like nothing more then comments on the question which should be edits updating what you know. YOu need to explain how it is an answer. You never told us in the question how you had connected them very clearly, how did you expect anyone to get that answer. This answer actually looks at a datasheet and explains what is missing.

Comment: @Kortuk: The schematic I posted in my answer is of the  "TB6612FNG Dual Motor Driver Carrier" made by Pololu. The schematic was obtained on the page antony links to in his question. The "TB6612FNG Dual Motor Driver Carrier" is a  break-out for the TB6612FNG integrated circuit, which antony calls the subcomponent. Maybe antony should spend a little time reading the page he linked to in his question so he can inform himself of what's what. He doesn't even recognize the schematic he linked to.

Comment: @Kortuk: I did look at the datasheet for the TB6612FNG to ensure that the IC was able to accept both a logic and motor power supply. Indeed it can, and they have different allowable voltage ranges. The breakout board, which is the device under question, should also have have two supplies unless it is a strangely designed. I think it is a very remote possibility that a VCC pin exists on the board that can be left not connected.  I find it bewildering that he insists that he doesn't need to power the chip!

Comment: Sigh, and now I see how I was interpreting the diagram wrong. I somehow failed to see that it's connecting pins on the IC to pins on the carrier board. It now doesn't make sense to me that it works.

Comment: @antony.trupe, use a voltmeter, what voltages do you see on the voltage pins, there is a good chance one is being fed through a diode or such.

Comment: @Kortuk less then a 10nth of a volt on logic power supply pins when the motor is not powered, but just shy of 5v when the motor is powered.

Comment: @anthony.trupe Have you tried powering VCC with 5V? I don't understand why after all this failure to troubleshoot, you still haven't given any feedback regarding the effectiveness of this suggestion. Nor have you accepted your own answer which maintains that Vcc is not needed. Which is it?

Comment: up until last night I was experiencing "success" without powering vcc. Last night I changed out the headers(de-soldered male, soldered female), and now have to power vcc to get it to work. I haven't been able to figure out what changed.